# How to check type of prop passing though one component to another component in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-proptypes

I am trying to render Apple Button on Signup and Sign in screen and I have created the component for the same so that I can reuse the component in the login and Sign up screen but I need to send a prop which `buttonType` so that I can render button according to screen.

for eg:

```
<View style={{ margin: 50, marginBottom: 10 }}>
                  <AppleSignButton buttontype={"AppleButton.Type.SIGN_UP"} />
                </View>
```

But I am getting an error if I am trying this.

Error: `Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNAppleAuthButtonViewManagerWhiteAppleButton.Type.SIGN_IN" was not found in the UIManager.`

AppleButton Component:

```
 <AppleButton
        buttonStyle={AppleButton.Style.WHITE}
        buttonType={props.buttontype} /* here if I try to replace it with "AppleButton.Type.SIGN_IN" then it outputs same error */
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 50,
        }}
        onPress={() => onAppleButtonPress()}
      />
```

Now, If I simply replace `props.buttontype` or `"AppleButton.Type.SIGN_IN"` this by `AppleButton.Type.SIGN_IN` it works fine.

So, my guess is that the prop I am sending to the component is in string format that's why the same error comes.

AppleButton Component:

```
export declare enum AppleButtonType {
  /**
   * The default button, the same as `SIGN_IN`.
   */
  DEFAULT = 'SignIn',

  /**
   * Renders the button with 'Sign in with Apple'.
   */
  SIGN_IN = 'SignIn',

  /**
   * Renders the button with 'Continue with Apple'.
   */
  CONTINUE = 'Continue',
  /**
   * Renders the button with 'Sign up with Apple'.
   *
   * > Note: This only works on iOS 13.2+. To check if the current device supports this, use the
   * provided `isSignUpButtonSupported` flag from the AppleAuth module.
   */
  SIGN_UP = 'SignUp',
}
```

Comment: How does the component that uses the `<AppleButton/>` look like? How was the `props` defined in there?

Comment: Why do you have quotes around `AppleButton.Type.SIGN_UP`? That makes it a string. For instance, `<AppleSignButton buttontype={"AppleButton.Type.SIGN_UP"} />` is the same as `<AppleSignButton buttontype="AppleButton.Type.SIGN_UP" />` (no `{}`). Don't you want `<AppleSignButton buttontype={AppleButton.Type.SIGN_UP} />` (no `""`)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just to check I have added quotes whether it gives me the same error or not. Yes, I want no quotes around `AppleButton.Type.SIGN_UP` but How can a get that prop Type?

Comment: @HanchenJiang Please see I have updated my post.